# ODBC Connection with IBM DB2 using PHP 5.1.6

Tags: php, odbc, db2, ibm-midrange, unixodbc

I'm using CentOS release 5.6 (Final) with PHP 5.1.6 (cli) (built: Feb  2 2012 18:24:47).
I need to connect with a DB2 database server in same local network.
Db2 version is V5R3.
I have installed iSeriesAccess client as well as unixODBC.

My odbc.ini configuration:

```
[iSeries Access ODBC Driver]
Description             = iSeries Access for Linux ODBC Driver
Driver          = /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib/libcwbodbc.so
Setup           = /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib/libcwbodbcs.so
NOTE1           = If using unixODBC 2.2.11 or later and you want the 32 and 64-bit ODBC drivers to share DSN's,
NOTE2           = the following Driver64/Setup64 keywords will provide that support.
Driver64                = /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib64/libcwbodbc.so
Setup64         = /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib64/libcwbodbcs.so
Threading               = 2
DontDLClose             = 1

UsageCount              = 1
```

i'm running the following code:

```
<?php
$database = 'dbname';
$server = 'local_ip';
$user = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$driver = 'iSeries Access ODBC Driver';



$conn = odbc_connect("Driver={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};Server=$server;Database=$database;", $user, $password);
if (!$conn......)
```

I'm getting the following error message:
"**[unixODBC][IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver]Missing system name needed for connection.Error!**"

Is there anything I'm missing? your suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Can try with a working odbc.ini configuration

[DB2]
Description     = ODBC for DB2
Driver          = /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib/libcwbodbc.so
Setup           = /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib/libcwbodbcs.so
FileUsage               = 1
Threading               = 2
DontDLClose             = 1
UsageCount              = 1

[mydb]
Driver = DB2
SYSTEM = 172.16.10.1
USER = username
PASSWORD = userpass
PORT = 50000
DATABASE = db11
Option = 1
```

Answer (score 5):

The `Server` property should be `System`.

More information can be found in the i5/OS Information Center for
[Connection string keywords](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaik%2Fconnectkeywords.htm) and [General properties](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaik%2Fconnectkeywords.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread: http://www.jitterbit.com/PhpBB/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=87

"Although this thread is a bit dated, I did get my AS/400 connection working. I had to use the "DSN" option and manually build the connection string."